# GKE autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I have three node pools in my cluster each of them have autoscaling enabled to go from 1-100 nodes. Minimum nodes are 1 for all. I am having something weird happening with autoscaling.

Scale down works fine for all pools.
Scale up seems to create a new node pool instead of scaling the corresponding node pools but since that node pool is missing the labels we need nothing gets scheduled and eventually gets destroyed.

I swear I am missing some information to enable it to scale the right node-pool, Any suggestions on what to look at and where to change? I do not use/have GCE auto-scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE starts new nodes only from user-created node pools. With **Node auto-provisioning** enabled, the cluster autoscaler can extend node pools automatically.  Node auto-provisioning automatically manages a set of node pools on the user's behalf. Since the nodepools here don't have labels, Node auto-provisioning is creating the new nodepools with required labels.

[Node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#workload_separation) might create node pools with labels and taints if all the following conditions are met:

- A pending Pod requires a node with a specific label key and value.
- The Pod has a toleration for a taint with the same key.
- The toleration is for the NoSchedule effect, NoExecute effect, or all effects.

You can update node labels and node taints for the [existing nodepools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/update-existing-nodepools#limitations) by disabling the autoscaling on the node pool. After the labels or taints are updated, [re-enable autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler#enabling_autoscaling_for_an_existing_node_pool).

To update node labels for a existing node pool, use the following command:

```
gcloud beta container node-pools update NODEPOOL_NAME \
        --node-labels=[NODE_LABEL,...] \
        [--cluster=CLUSTER_NAME] [--region=REGION | --zone=ZONE]
        [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

**Note:** The cluster autoscaler is automatically enabled when using node auto-provisioning.

Refer to [Node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#overview)  for more information.